# Convert ANSI to UTF8

Tags: c#, encoding, windows-phone-8.1

I download a file from the internet in C# Windows Phone 8.1. The problem is, that the downloaded content has strange looking special characters. When I examined the file on my PC with Notepad++, it told me, that the file is encoded in `ANSI` and I want to read it as `UTF8`

Here my code

```
byte[] responseBytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync("http://somesite/myfile.txt");
string content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
```

But as it is encoded in ANSI, all special characters are displayed strange.

Now after some research, a lot of people have this approach:

```
Encoding ANSI = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
byte[] ansiBytes = ANSI.GetBytes(str);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(ANSI, Encoding.UTF8, ansiBytes);
String utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

but in WP 8.1, the routine `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)` is invalid, as well as `Encoding.Default`.
What can I do, to have my string in UTF8?

Comment: the **-1** in `string content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length -1);` might be unnecessary (changed it in the code), but that does not solve the problem...

Comment: The edit you suggested on my answer was using the class *wrongly*, as the start of my answer attempted to explain. **Do not do this**. It’s entirely redundant. The correct way of using my class is like in the first code example of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general (but apparently not on Windows Phone), the way to do this is to simply use the correct encoding from the get-go:

```
string content = Encoding.Default.GetString(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
```

Where [`Encoding.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default(v=vs.110).aspx) is defined as:

> an encoding for the operating system's current ANSI code page.

… What you are currently attempting to do is interpret the bytes in an *incorrect* encoding, and then try to re-encode them. This won’t generally work.

---

But as you’ve said, **Windows Phone does not support this**. So what you do instead is to manually create a byte-to-character [translation table for Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Code_page_layout) and look up the characters. You can then either manually loop over the input buffer, or, for extra points, create a new class which derives from `System.Text.Encoding` and which implements the required encoding.

In fact, if I remember C# conversions correctly, you don’t even need a lookup table. The following is a rudimentary but (for your purposes) sufficient `Encoding` implementation:

```
class Windows1252Encoding : System.Text.Encoding {
    public override int GetByteCount(char[] chars, int index, int count) {
        return count;
    }

    public override int GetBytes(char[] chars, int charIndex, int charCount, byte[] bytes, int byteIndex) {
        Array.Copy(chars, charIndex, bytes, byteIndex, charCount);
        return charCount;
    }

    public override int GetCharCount(byte[] bytes, int index, int count) {
        return count;
    }

    public override int GetChars(byte[] bytes, int byteIndex, int byteCount, char[] chars, int charIndex) {
        Array.Copy(bytes, byteIndex, chars, charIndex, byteCount);
        return byteCount;
    }

    public override int GetMaxByteCount(int charCount) {
        return charCount;
    }

    public override int GetMaxCharCount(int byteCount) {
        return byteCount;
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but I cannot test it on Windows Phone, only on Mono.